# SQLAlchemy sais moduel not callebel

Tags: python, flask

> This is my .py code that raises the error:

```py
@app.route('/home/logedin/', methods=["get", "post"])
def verLogIn():
    passW = request.form['pass']
    email = request.form['email']
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///databases/users.db', echo=True)
    meta = MetaData()
    users = Table(
        'users',
        meta,
        Column('email', String, primary_key=True),
        Column('passWH', String),
    )
    meta.create_all(engine)
    """ ins1 = users.insert()
    ins1 = users.insert().values(email=email, passWH=passW)
    ins2 = users.insert()
    ins2 = users.insert().values(passWH=passW)
    conn = engine.connect()
    result = conn.execute(ins1)
    result = conn.execute(ins2) """
    q = True
    while q:
        emailQ = session.query(users).first()
        if emailQ == email:
            passWQ = session.query(users).first()
            if passWQ == passW:
                return "PTrue"
            else:
                return "PFalse"
                break
        else:
            q = False
            return "EFalse"
```

My error is: Moduel not callebel, it refers to the emailQ and passWQ variables. I tried assigning them to other variables and then calling them, but the same error is thrown. 
This is the traceback:
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

> I searched online but everything I found was useless
>
> What should I do?

Comment: Please show us the actual error and traceback. I don't think Python ever says "Moduel not callebel".

Comment: I've added the traceback

Comment: Full traceback, all the lines, not just "This is the traceback: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable".

Comment: Is `session` Flask's session object or a Flask-SQLAlchemy-Session object? If it's the former, then could be the problem.

Comment: I do not exactly understand your question. This is how I declared the session object: 
from sqlalchemy.orm import session

Comment: Should have I imported it from flask. This is what you mean? If I do that the traceback is:
AttributeError: 'SecureCookieSession' object has no attribute 'query'

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a session maker.
 1. Makes a session 
    
        `from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()`
 3. Access the session